# Does any discrete signal has z-transform (even noise)?

Tags: z-transform

I faced to the following discrete

$$
y[n+1]=Ay[n]+Bx[n]+\eta[n]
$$

where $y[n] \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ and $B$ are matrices with appropriate dimension, and $\eta[n]$ is noise.

I have no problem with the following

$$
y[n+1]=Ay[n]+Bx[n] 
$$

Because I can write the z-transform as follows

$$
zY(z)-zY(0)=AY(z)+BX(z) 
$$

Can I simply write the following even for noise?

$$
zY(z)-zy(0)=AY(z)+BX(z)+ H(z) 
$$

Please answer it conceptually and explain it.

Comment: If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |w[n]| r^n < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x[n]| r^n < \infty$ and $y[n+1] = A y[n]+B x[n]+w[n]$ then for $0 < |z| < \min(r,1/\|A\|) $ :  $$z^{-1}(-y[0] +\sum_{n=0}^\infty y[n] z^n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty y[n+1] z^n = A\sum_{n=0}^\infty y[n] z^n+B\sum_{n=0}^\infty x[n] z^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty w[n] z^n$$

Comment: What is the meaning of the constraint that you have for the noise $w[n]$? I understand that it comes from definition of z-transformation but it is not tangible for me? which structure has be enforced to the noise to have that condition?

Comment: For example $E[ |w[n]|^2] < C < \infty$ implies $E[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|w[n]|^2}{n^2}] < \infty$ so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|w[n]|}{n^4} < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |w[n]| r^n < \infty$ for $r < 1$